# How to load .dae object with texture, and material

Tags: minko

I just started with Minko and trying to undestand this https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/doc/tutorial/06-Loading_3D_files.md tutorial. I did some steps:

```
sceneManager->assets()->loader()
        ->queue(FIREAXE_D)
        ->queue(FIREAXE_N)
        ->queue(FIREAXE_S)
        ->queue(TEXTURE_FILENAME)
        ->queue("effect/Basic.effect")
        ->queue(OBJ_MODEL_FILENAME);
```

and now I am trying to use these three textures with my object and file .mtl -> material.

```
auto _ = sceneManager->assets()->loader()->complete()->connect([=](file::Loader::Ptr loader)
    {

        auto objModel = sceneManager->assets()->symbol(OBJ_MODEL_FILENAME);
         objModel->component<Transform>()->matrix()->appendScale(0.01f);
         objModel->component<Transform>()->matrix()->translation(-1.f, -1.f, 0.f);
         objModel->component<Texture>()->set(sceneManager->assets()->texture(FIREAXE_D));
         //objModel->addComponent(sceneManager->assets()->texture(FIREAXE_N));
         //objModel->addComponent(sceneManager->assets()->texture(FIREAXE_S));
         root->addChild(objModel);
    });
```

This won't work and what about .mtl file? How to attach it to my object?

However tutorials are still to tiny and buggy it is better to look for examples but I cann't find any with texture loading for object right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This won't work and what about .mtl file? How to attach it to my object?

Your question is about loading a Collada (*.dae) file. Collada files don't have *.mtl files, *.obj files do.

Still, it works the same for any dependency of any file: they are automatically loaded if they can actually be found at the provided path/URI.

You can add include/search paths using the `file::Options::includePaths()` property, or customize how URI are resolved by using the `file::Options::uriFunction()`. Many other properties of the `file::Options` class will help you customizing how assets are loaded.

> However tutorials are still to tiny and buggy

If you find bugs please open [an issue on github](https://github.com/aerys/minko/issues).

> it is better to look for examples but I cann't find any with texture loading for object right now.

The following example loads a Collada file along with animations and textures:

https://github.com/aerys/minko/tree/master/example/assimp

Comment: I looked on this example before.
In Assimp example I get object and it's dancing all the time :)
However in code there are specifed some keys for turns and jumps. I am not sure if it is working well. But I suppose it should better to show a monster who got defined textures and actions like walk, run and jump. So everyone could see what happens.